# Proving a graph is connected iff it has no isolated points

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

How do I prove that a graph is connected iff it has no isolated points?
I can do the first half; if the graph is connected, any pair of vertices have a walk between them. Suppose there is an isolated point. Since an isolated point has no edges, it is impossible for it to have a walk between another vertex, a contradiction. Hence, a connected graph cannot have an isolated point.
How do I prove the converse?
I imagine I'm supposed to construct a procedure like going from marking one vertices one at a time, and say at some point the vertex which is the intended finish of the walk has to be marked since there are only finite vertices in the graph.
But I can't go further than this rough sketch.

Comment: Is this not false for the graph with a single vertex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false.  Consider for example the graph consisting of vertex set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and edge set $\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The converse is false.

Take a graph on four vertices with edges between the first and second and between the third and fourth vertex (and no other edges).